# how to get realtime new transaction data in nodejs from bitcore

Tags: json-rpc, nodes, bitcore, query

I want to run a private node, and use it to receive realtime unconfirmed transactions data into my nodejs script.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you use some nodejs library which would give you a high level wrapper for the bitcoin core api `getrawmempool`, or make your script hit your local bitcoin instance in the json-rpc format to get the memorypool data your node has.
The memory pool is basically where the transactions stay before getting confirmed in a block. So your script needs to run in regular intervals of time to keep track of the changes too.

`url: http://<username>:<password>@localhost:18332/
post data:{"jsonrpc":1,"id":"curltext", "method":"getrawmempool", "payload":[]}`

The username and password is checked from the bitcoin.conf file in the .bitcoin folder. Change the port number to 8332 in case you are running the mainnet daemon.

Comment: how do I get my nodejs script to send a json-rpc method?

Comment: use any request package with which you can post data to any url

Comment: Ah okay, I was hoping for some sort of a websocket connection/ ethereum .filter() function sort of a thing. Thanks though!